# Can I keep new words in dictionary by matching key as prefix

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, optimization

I have a dictionary say,

```
stringToListDict = {'foo' : [], 'bar' : []}
```

Now lets say we do

+foofoo

```
stringToListDict = {'foo' : ['foofoo'], 'bar' : []}
```

+barbar

```
stringToListDict = {'foo' : ['foofoo'], 'bar' : ['barbar']}
```

+foobarbar

```
stringToListDict = {'foo' : ['foofoo', 'foobarbar'], 'bar' : ['barbar']}
```

+notMatchingAnyKey

```
Simply discard this new string.
```

As you can see the added string goes by matching keys as prefix.

I can do this by traversing through each key one by one of the dictionary till I get a matching prefix. But is there any other elegant or efficient approach? You don't have to worry of edge scenarios like what would happen if :

```
stringToListDict = {'foo' : ['foofoo'], 'foobar' : [], 'bar' : ['barbar']}

then +foobarbar
```

FYI, this is not an assignment.

Comment: wait, what is the matching criteria? The first 3 letters?

Comment: Complete key has to match. Any of them. No case of collision in my scenario, so need not worry about foo and foobar keys. Keys and input strings can be of any length.

Comment: Sorry but you have me confued. What does `+foofoo` mean in code? can you show us?

Comment: +foofoo means you are trying to put this string in the best possible matching key under the dictionary. 

Just like on "An"-prefixed page, you should see words like "Ant", "And", "Analog" etc which starts with "An".

Comment: If you're using a dict, then yes, the only option here would be to iterate all the keys, something like `for k, v in d.items(): if s.startswith(k): v.append(s)`. A different data structure, like a search tree or a trie, could make this more efficient (logarithmic rather than linear time), although it won't be much _simpler_ (because the dict is already pretty simple to use).

Comment: As a side note, don't use the name `dict` for your dictionaries; that hides the name of the type, and eventually you're going to write `d = dict(my_list_of_pairs)` and get a baffling error about dict not being callable.

Comment: ok @abarnert thank for that info. One ques, how I can improve your code to handle the edge case mentioned in the end of the ques.

Comment: You will be far better off with a mapping based on prefix-trees, if you want to keep this scalable, because you can't benefit from standard hashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a dict, then yes, you will have to iterate all of the keys to find any that match. Dicts are built on hash tables, and hash functions don't have any notion of "starts with" or "close" to take advantage of (in fact, they're specifically designed to give very different outputs for close inputs).

It's not at all hard to do what you want:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if s.startswith(k):
        v.append(s)
        break
else:
    # whatever you want to do if no prefix exists
```

But it *is* inefficient if the dict is large, because you're doing a linear search.

---

You can make make it linear in the length of the key, rather than the length of the dict (which will actually be *slower* in your test case, but probably faster in most cases where performance matters):

```
for i in range(len(s), 0, -1):
    try:
        d[k[:i]].append(s)
        break
    except KeyError:
        pass
else:
    # whatever you want to do if no prefix exists
```

---

But if you need optimal efficiency, you want to look at a logarithmic data structure, like a balanced binary search tree, a b-tree, a skiplist, a trie, or even just a plain old list kept in sorted order. Most implementations of such types that you can find on PyPI or the ActiveState recipe repository will have a method to find the insert location for a key in sorted order. Or, if you're using a plain old list, just use the `bisect` module in the stdlib. Just check the key before that insert location, and either it starts with your key, or nothing does.

For example, with a [`sortedcontainers.SortedDict`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/):

```
i = d.bisect(s)
if d.iloc[i].startswith(s):
    d[d.iloc[i]].append(s)
else:
    # whatever you want to do if no prefix exists
```

A prefix trie will probably be the most efficient if you have a huge, dense set of keys and you're doing lots of queries as well as inserts. But for different characteristics, others might win out. So, if this matters, you'd want to try a few and test.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the prefix match using a function like:

#### Code:

```
def append_longest_prefix(data_dict, to_append):
    for i in range(1, len(to_append)):
        if to_append[:-i] in data_dict:
            data_dict[to_append[:-i]].append(to_append)
            return
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = {'foo': [], 'bar': []}

append_longest_prefix(data, 'foofoo')
append_longest_prefix(data, 'barbar')
append_longest_prefix(data, 'foobarbar')
append_longest_prefix(data, 'notMatchingAnyKey')

print(data)

data = {'foo' : ['foofoo'], 'foobar' : [], 'bar' : ['barbar']}
append_longest_prefix(data, 'foobarbar')
print(data)
```

#### Result:

```
{'foo': ['foofoo', 'foobarbar'], 'bar': ['barbar']}

{'foo': ['foofoo'], 'foobar': ['foobarbar'], 'bar': ['barbar']}
```

Comment: Will your code handle the edge case mentioned at the end of the question.

Comment: Which edge case?

Comment: stringToListDict = {'foo' : ['foofoo'], 'foobar' : [], 'bar' : ['barbar']}

then +foobarbar

Comment: Yes, it matches the longest prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
_dict = {'foo' : [], 'bar' : []}

def _add(_str):
    for _key in _dict.keys(): # loop _dict keys
        if _str.startswith(_key): # check if _str starts with _dict _key
            _dict[_key].append(_str) # append _str to _dict based on _key

_add("foofoo")
_add("barbar")
_add("foobarbar")
_add("notMatchingAnyKey")

# {'foo': ['foofoo', 'foobarbar'], 'bar': ['barbar']}
```

---

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/SFqjdY)